# Parsing JSON in python for second object

Tags: python, json

I have a sample JSON in this format:

JSON FILE:

```
{
   "Name": "ABC",
   "Phone":"123",
   "Address":[{"City":"City-1"},{"Country":"Country-1"}]
}

{
   "Name": "ABC-1",
   "Phone":"123-1",
   "Address":[{"City":"City-2"},{"Country":"Country-2"}]
}
```

Is there any approach to parse the JSON and loop through the file and print each `key-value` pair.

The approach I used was through using

```
json_open = open(json_file)
json_data = json.load(json_open)
print(json_data[Name]) ##should give ABC
print(json_data[Name]) ##should give ABC-1 - unsure about the syntax and format
```

But I'm currently able to print only the first object values - i.e. `name=ABC` and not `name=ABC-1`

Comment: Can you add expected output too for the sample provided?

Comment: Is this a valid json ? It should be only one dictionary not multiple dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your json file. I modified your json and written code for traverse each element in it.

> Error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 9:
... "Country-1" }]}{    "Name": "ABC-1",
-------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

> sample.json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Phone": "123",
      "Address": [
        {
          "City": "City-1"
        },
        {
          "Country": "Country-1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "ABC-1",
      "Phone": "123-1",
      "Address": [
        {
          "City": "City-2"
        },
        {
          "Country": "Country-2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> sample.py

```
import json

json_file='sample.json'
with open(json_file, 'r') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

jin=data['data']

for emp in jin:
      print ("Name :"+emp["Name"])
      print ("Phone :"+emp["Phone"])
      print ("City :"+emp["Address"][0]["City"])
      print ("Country :"+emp["Address"][1]["Country"])
```

Comment: I see that you've encountered an error while parsing the json, but a json can exist in this format - 

`{

Key:value,
Key:value
}

{

Key:value,
Key:value
}`

I'm trying to parse a json of this type, rather than converting it to array as you've done in your modified json file.

Comment: Each record on json file is separated by ','. So, your file should look like:

   ` [{
  "Name": "ABC",
  "Phone": "123",
  "Address": [{
   "City": "City-1"
  }, {
   "Country": "Country-1"
  }]
 },

 {
  "Name": "ABC-1",
  "Phone": "123-1",
  "Address": [{
   "City": "City-2"
  }, {
   "Country": "Country-2"
  }]
 }
    ]`

Answer (score 0):

Each record on json file is separated by ','. So, your file should look like:

```
[{
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Phone": "123",
    "Address": [{
        "City": "City-1"
    }, {
        "Country": "Country-1"
    }]
},

{
    "Name": "ABC-1",
    "Phone": "123-1",
    "Address": [{
        "City": "City-2"
    }, {
        "Country": "Country-2"
    }]
}
]
```

You can read the file and output as follows :

```
import json

my_file='test.json'
with open(my_file, 'r') as  my_data:
    data = json.load(my_data)

print data

for elm in data:
    print elm['Phone']
    print elm['Name']
    print elm['Address'][0]['City']
    print elm['Address'][1]['Country']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not valid json format,

You can check [here](http://jsonlint.com/) you json format

You should use this try.json file

```
{
    "data":[{
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Phone":"123",
        "Address":[{"City":"City-1"},{"Country":"Country-1"}]
        }, {
        "Name": "ABC-1",
        "Phone":"123-1",
        "Address":[{"City":"City-2"},{"Country":"Country-2"}]
    }]
}
```

here is try.py

```
import json
json_open = open("try.json")
json_data = json.load(json_open)
for i in range(len(json_data['data'])):
    print(json_data['data'][i]["Name"])
```

Note : python code is written in python3

output is look line this

```
ABC
ABC-1
```